How to make two parallel tasks in ReactPHP Event Loop see each other's DB changes within the same transaction?
I'm writing PHPUnit test cases for a PHP application and I'm using the ReactPHP event loop to run two tasks in parallel. Both tasks are using the same database connection and the transaction is started in the main function where the event loop is created.
Here's a simplified version of my code:
function testXyzScenario() {
    $loop->futureTick(function() {
        // Task 1: waits (by adding timer function in loop) for task to create a job for it. and then save the results for task 2 in DB.
    });

    $loop->futureTick(function() {
        // Task 2: task 2 creates a job for task 1. and wait (using sleep function) for results from task 1.
    });

    $loop->run();
}

The problem I'm facing is that Task 2 is not seeing the changes made by Task 1. However, Task 1 can see the job created by Task 2.
I believe this is because task 2 is using the sleep function which blocks the event loop and when task 2 gives up waiting for results by task 1. task 1 saves the result in DB.
But I can not remove the sleep function in task 2 because it is not directly being used by task 2 it is used by an API of the same app which is being called by task 2.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Interesting case. One thing to notice is that you're not actually running things in parallel, the event loop just manages all outstanding tasks efficiently. When calling sleep() everything is blocked, even the event loop, so Task 1 can't do anything because the loop can't react (taken from what you described above).
From my point of view it sounds like you have a specific sequence of tasks here and I think this should be reflected by your test:

Task 1 waits to receive a task
Task 2 creates a task and gives it to Task 1
Once the the task is done, Task 1 will save result and needs to inform Task 2
Task 2 accesses the result

This also means that you have to wait between these steps until the previous one finishes on order to move on. You could take a look at Promises for this. Hard to say what the best approach here is without seeing how the Tasks themselves work.
